# Proof that $h^{2H} \cdot \frac12 \left[ (n+1)^{2H} - 2n^{2H} + (n-1)^{ 2H} \right]$ has only one root in $[0,1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: analysis, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-analysis

So, I am a little bit confused, how can I proof that
$$f(H):=h^{2H} \cdot \frac12 \left[ (n+1)^{2H} - 2n^{2H} + (n-1)^{ 2H} \right]$$
has only one root in $[0,1]$ for all $h>0$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

It's easy to see the root $H=\frac12$.

Comment: You might be able to prove that $f(H)=0$ implies $f'(H)>0$.

Comment: Huuu? That would mean $H=\frac12$ is a minimum? I think it should be positive vor $H>1/2$ and negative for smaller than $1/2$...

Comment: The idea is, if you know every root in an interval is an up-crossing, you are done, because up- and down-crossings interleave on intervals.

Comment: Ah, yeah! Of course. But I am not seeing any idea for proofing that...

Comment: Here's a hint.  For given $A,B>0$, how many _real_ solutions of $\exp(At)+\exp(-Bt)=2$ are there?  And how many positive ones can there be?

Comment: Okay, that's something I know, but I don't have any source for that... So of course only one positive solution.